# How to solve 'Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails"'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

Any idea why this error: compatible versions for gem.

```
  @ -SVE1411EGXB:~/refine/active/myapp$ bundle install
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
    Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    Resolving dependencies...
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
      In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)

  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms-core (~> 2.1.2) ruby depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 2.3.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
 @ -SVE1411EGXB:~/refine/active/myapp$ ls
app  config  config.ru  db  doc  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  lib  log  public  Rakefile  README.rdoc  script  test  tmp  vendor
 @ -SVE1411EGXB:~/refine/active/myapp$ rm Gemfile.lock 
 @ -SVE1411EGXB:~/refine/active/myapp$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using multi_json 1.10.1
~
~
~
~
~
~

Using refinerycms-resources 2.1.2
Using refinerycms 2.1.2
Installing refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 1.0.0
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using uglifier 2.5.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
 @ -SVE1411EGXB:~/refine/active/myapp$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.18 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-06-22 22:41:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-22 22:41:21] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-06-22 22:41:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4941 port=3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that your `refinerycms-core` gem relied on an older version of `jquery-rails` (specifically version `2.3.0`).

Since you were trying to install a newer version of jquery-rails (`3.1.0`), `bundler` was warning you that you could break compatibility by installing the newest version.

When you erased your `Gemfile.lock`, you erased all the "locked" versions of each Gem that you had, and therefore started from scratch. You will now have the newer version of `refinerycms-core` which will work with `jquery-rails` `3.1.0`

Comment: Thanks @Martin Konecny . Now I KNOW why this did the trick :)